Python: weird characters in extract_message
I use extract_message from pypi.org/project/extract-msg package to extract outlook messages. It works well until this outlook file causes the error message. I found out that the problem is that the email content contains some weird characters like â–ª which cause the error ? Any idea how to make ignore these weird characters ?
msg = extract_msg.Message(email)
2024-12-11 16:02:00,865 - ERROR : [message_base.py:97 - __init__] Critical error accessing the body. File opened but accessing the body will throw an exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\miniconda\envs\spy_3_10\lib\cmd.py", line 214, in onecmd
    func = getattr(self, 'do_' + cmd)
AttributeError: 'InterruptiblePdb' object has no attribute 'do_msg'. Did you mean: 'do_s'?

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\miniconda\envs\spy_3_10\lib\site-packages\extract_msg\msg_classes\message_base.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.body
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\miniconda\envs\spy_3_10\lib\functools.py", line 981, in __get__
    val = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\miniconda\envs\spy_3_10\lib\site-packages\extract_msg\msg_classes\message_base.py", line 944, in body
    if (body := self.getStringStream('__substg1.0_1000')) is not None:
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\miniconda\envs\spy_3_10\lib\site-packages\extract_msg\msg_classes\msg.py", line 738, in getStringStream
    return None if tmp is None else tmp.decode(self.stringEncoding)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\miniconda\envs\spy_3_10\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2279: character maps to <undefined>


Is extract_message your own code, or do you mean this https://pypi.org/project/extract-msg/ package?

i am actually using the extract-msg python package.

You face a mojibake case. Your email content is utf-8 and you misinterpret it as cp1252: '▪'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252') returns â–ª while e.g. '━'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252') leads to UnicodeDecodeError as '━'.encode( 'utf-8') returns b'\xe2\x94\x81' which contains byte 0x81 …
